# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to generate id using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` for fill `userData.AspNetUserID` property and I got this error message in my console:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "JET", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.

Can anyone help fix this error?

This is my code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> CopyUserRole(int id)
    { 
        var result  = _context.UserData.Where(m => m.UserDataID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        var userData = new UserData();
        var email = result.Email.Insert(0, "copy-");

        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = email, Email = email };
        var UserManager = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "12345678");

        if(!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(result.Role))
        {
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(result.Role));
        }

        var success = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, result.Role);

        //userData.UserDataID     = 0;
        userData.AspNetUserID   = user.Id;
        userData.DeviceID       = result.DeviceID;
        userData.PhotoUrl       = result.PhotoUrl;
        userData.Status         = result.Status;
        userData.Role           = result.Role;
        userData.Name           = result.Name+" - Copy";
        userData.Area           = result.Area;
        userData.FilePhotoURL1  = result.FilePhotoURL1;
        userData.Email          = email;
        userData.LihatJurnal    = result.LihatJurnal;
        userData.UserDataArea   = result.UserDataArea;
        userData.UserDataMenu   = result.UserDataMenu;
        userData.UserDataGudang = result.UserDataGudang;
        userData.UserDataPerkiraan = result.UserDataPerkiraan;

        try
        {
            _context.UserData.Add(userData);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception Ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n ======================== \n");
            Console.WriteLine("\n " + Ex + " \n");
            Console.WriteLine("\n ======================== \n");
        }

        return Json(userData);
    }
```

Comment: How come a user is in a role but the role does not exist! `if(!await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(result.Role))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to create a user with the same Username, which cause `user` to be the instance of the same user. Calling `AddToRoleAsync` on the same user cause the error because the user has already had the role. You should try to create user with different email.